# Read prompt from Process StandardOut when requiring input

Tags: c#, .net, stream

I am using System.Diagnostics.Process to create a new process and communicate with the operating system to run a command.

The command will at times require a username, password, both, nothing.

If I read from StandardOutput it will immediately exit.  If I just blindly provide a password\n when I know it requires a password in a test scenario, it works, authenticates with third party, and I can read from StandardOutput to get the results.

As a test I tried this:

```
            while (_process.StandardOutput.Peek() > -1)
            Log.Info((char)_process.StandardOutput.Read());
```

This will cause the command to immediate exit with a failed to complete exit code.  I tried all sorts of ways of doing it, but I can't figure out a way to figure out if it requires a username or password or has them already (in which it just outputs the result set).

I need to do (pseudo code)

```
shellCommand(args)
ReadOutput()
if (requiresUsername)
   supplyUsernmame
if (requiresPassword)
   supplyPassword
OutputResults()
```

I know the command will show Username or Password for the first word if it requires either and then wait for me to supply it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the basic to start:

```
Process myProcess = new Process();
myProcess .StartInfo.FileName = "yourCommand.exe";
myProcess .StartInfo.Arguments = "-yourArguments";
myProcess .StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;//do not open shell window
myProcess .StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true; // allows you to manipulate or suppress the output of a process
myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;// allows you to manipulate or suppress the input of a process
myProcess .Start()
```

After this, things are very dependable of the output of youCommand.exe.

If yourCommand.exe ask for user in a line and the prompt caret goes to a new line like **Enter user name: /r/n** then you can do a process.StandardOutput.ReadLine(); and parse the line to see if is asking for the user or is another message.

If no new line you have to deal with a `thread.sleep` and a loop to see when yourCommand.exe ask for input.

An example with new line when ask for user and no new line when ask for password:

This is yourCommand.exe

```
class ConsoleApplication1
{
    void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("User:");
        string user = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Password:");//no new line!!!
        string pass = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("The user {0} has the password {1}", user, pass));
    }
}
```

And this is what you are trying to do:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
 class Program
 {
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
   Process myProcess = new Process();
   myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Users\joseluis.vaquero\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Prototipos\ConsoleApplication1\bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe";
   // myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "-yourArguments";
   myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;//do not open shell window
   myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true; // allows you to manipulate or suppress the output of a process
   myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;// allows you to manipulate or suppress the input of a process
   myProcess.Start();
 //  Thread.Sleep(1000);//no need to wait, next ReadLine wait for you
   Console.WriteLine(myProcess.StandardOutput.ReadLine());
   myProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine("jlvaquero");//send user name to consoleapp1
   Thread.Sleep(1000);//need to wait consoleapp1 to ask for pwd because we can not use ReadLine
   char[] myBuffer = new char[1];
   while (myBuffer[0] != ':') //read until double dot wich is the last char of "Password:"
   {
     myProcess.StandardOutput.Read(myBuffer, 0, 1);
    Console.Write(myBuffer[0]);
   }
   Console.WriteLine();//just to get readable output for the example
   myProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine("1234");//send pwd to consoleapp1
   Console.Write(myProcess.StandardOutput.ReadLine());//show the output of consoleapp1
   Console.Read();
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: It does not have a new line, I tried peek and Read() but it causes the process to exit abruptly.  I don't know how to get around that.  

It basically is something along the lines of.

Username not provided, please enter username: <>
Password is invalid, please enter password: <>

Comment: @Michael. Can you add the username and pass in the arguments of the binary? Because with myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "-yourArguments"; maybe you do not need a interactive process.

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  And if I could, it still doesn't solve the problem when the wrong credentials are provided (as that will again force a prompt and lock up the application that calls it).

But I think I might know a bit more what is going on.  The command is spawning a second process that is handling the communication with the remote service, and I think the output might be piped from there, but I don't have a handle on that application so I am unable to see it.  I am not sure if there is even a practical way to do it.

Comment: Well, with the info you put in the question and the mess with the second process I think I can not do more. I'm sorry.

Comment: I appreciate your feedback, I think the second process is what is causing all the grief, I didn't realize it was doing that initially and spent a ton of time banging my head against a wall.  I'm trying to find another way around it using a native DLL solution.  I voted up your solution as helpful.